# Animate symbol on multiple geodesic polylines

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, overlay, polyline, geodesic-sphere

I want to animate symbols though multiple geodesic polylines...i tired to do this in a  for loop. the lines get drawn but the circle (symbol) does not animate..it just stays at the starting point here is my code.

```
    var poly;
    var geodesic;
    var map;
    var clickcount = 0;

    function initialize() {


        var styles = [{ featureType: "landscape", stylers: [{ color: "#000514"}] }, { featureType: "administrative.country", stylers: [{ weight: 0.1 }, { color: "#009acd"}] }, { featureType: "water", stylers: [{ color: "#1f4fa5dc"}] }, { featureType: "road", stylers: [{ color: "#000514"}] }, { featureType: "administrative.locality", stylers: [{ color: "#7cfc00" }, { visibility: "off"}] }, { featureType: "landscape.man_made", stylers: [{ visibility: "off"}] }, { featureType: "poi", stylers: [{ visibility: "off"}] }, { featureType: "administrative.province", stylers: [{ visibility: "on"}]}];
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(7.3, 80.6333),
            zoom: 3,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);
        map.setOptions({ styles: styles });

        var lineSymbol = {
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            scale: 2,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000'
        };


        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < 50; i = i + 5) {


            var flightPlanCoordinates = [
            new google.maps.LatLng(7.3, 80.6333),
            new google.maps.LatLng(23.772323 + i, -102.214897 - i)];
            var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                icons: [{ icon: lineSymbol, offset: '100%'}],
                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 1,
                geodesic: true                  
            });

            polyline.setMap(map);
            animateCircle();
        }
    }

    function animateCircle() {
        var count = 0;
        offsetId = window.setInterval(function () {
            count = (count + 1) % 200;

            var icons = polyline.get('icons');
            icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
            polyline.set('icons', icons);
        }, 20);
    }
```

please help me on this one..i would love to see this work :) thank you very much.

Comment: See this post. This worked for me.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644427/multiple-polyline-to-a-marker-on-google-maps-api-v3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your polyline variable is out of animateCircle function's scope. You have to use closure, getting code out of animateCircle function and pasting it in place of its call *should* do the trick.

Edit: I messed up closure as usual ;-)
You can do it like that (again, untested):

```
//vars
var poliylines = new Array();

function initialize() {
    //unchanged code

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i = i + 5) {
        //unchanged code
        polylines[i] = polyline;
        animateCircle(i);
    }
}

function animateCircle(var id) {
    var count = 0;
    offsetId = window.setInterval(function () {
        count = (count + 1) % 200;

        var icons = polylines[id].get('icons');
        icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
        polylines[id].set('icons', icons);
    }, 20);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the reply.. :) it now animates only one symbol..others are still in still sitting there..is there anyy way that i could animate all the symbols?

Comment: WOOOWWWWW...maaan ur a genius..thank you very much..!!! :) much appreciated for ur tym n help ..thanks again..it works!!!...

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple answer to this problem. I am using google maps api v3. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-animate

Scroll down below and click on **html+javascript tab** we have variable **lineCoordinates**. Here we can pass a set of objects instead of 2 objects like this:

```
var lineCoordinates = [
new google.maps.LatLng(latitude1, longitude1),
new google.maps.LatLng(latitude2, longitude2),
new google.maps.LatLng(latitude3, longitude3),
new google.maps.LatLng(latitude4, longitude4)
];
```

The animation will now happen across all objects in lineCoordinates. In this examples case 4  polylines.